# populate FormBuilder from a service in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an Angular2 model that I'm populating via a service.  I would like to use this model to then populate my form (built from `FormBuilder`) so my users can edit the data.

Here is what I am currently doing, but I get errors for fields that exist in my model that are not being exposed in my form.

```
  ...
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.buildForm();
    this.get('1');
  }
  get(id: string) {
    this.myModelsService.get(id)
      .subscribe(
        d => {
          this.myModel = d;
          this.myForm.setValue(d);
        },
        error => console.log(error)
      );
  }
```

This works, however I get errors like `Cannot find form control with name: incidentTimeStamp`.

Should I be first deleting attributes that I know do not have corresponding form controls? Or is there a better way to do what I am trying to do?

Being able to populate fields for edit seems like a pretty basic building block, and this seems like it is way harder than it should be.

Comment: Can you share the HTML part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use [FormGroup.patchValue()](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/forms/src/model.ts#L971)

`FormGroup.setValue()` does strict checks, while `FormGroup.patchValue()` does not.